# finding my tomcat on my machine

Tags: jsp, tomcat

First, my computer is windows 7 64bit, with xampp(apache, php, mysql), vmware server, java installed.

http://localhost => auto redirect to http://localhost/xampp
https://localhost:8333/ui/# (vmware server web access page)
C:\xampp\tomcat (tomcat folder)
C:\xampp\htdocs\ (php files directory)

i've tried to place a blank jsp file to C:\xampp\htdocs\jsp\test.jpg and run 
http://localhost/jsp/test.jsp, there is a text display

```
cannot find current JDK installation
```

now, i want to make my machine to run jsp, when i enter http://127.0.0.1/examples/index.html, there is a tomcat web server page error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /examples/index.html

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /examples/index.html

description The requested resource (/examples/index.html) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.16
```

i want to ask, where is my tomcat home directory? what is the url & port number to run jsp examples?

thanks

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\jsp\test.jpg is an image not a jsp. is this a typo or did you give your file a jpg ext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to note.

The readme file for xampp's Tomcat addon has what you are looking for
http://www.apachefriends.org/winxampp/readme-addon-tomcat.txt
It indicates that

```
Tomcat Server Home  =   .\xampp\tomcat
Tomcat URL          =   http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Tomcat Doc Root     =   .\xampp\tomcat\webapps

Tomcat example Root =   .\xampp\tomcat\webapps\examples
Tomcat example URL  =   http://127.0.0.1/examples/
```

So your web applications should be going under the `.\xampp\tomcat\webapps` directory

Also what version of the JDK do you have installed? The error message `cannot find current JDK installation` indicates that you don't have a version of the JDK installed or setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

The default [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) installation directory should be: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0`

Answer (score 0):

```
Tomcat Server Home  =   .\xampp\tomcat
Tomcat URL          =   http://127.0.0.1:8080/ / http://localhost:8080/
Tomcat Doc Root     =   .\xampp\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
```